# What is the meaning of SIR-model in context with epidemic spreading like covid-19

Tags: covid-19

In context of epidemiology we encounter the acronym SIR-model.
What does it stand for?

Answer (score 1):

SIR model
"(Engl .: Susceptible-Infected-Recovered-Model)
Mathematical model in which the spread
a certain infectious disease in one
Model population with the variables
- "Susceptible - S" (susceptible),
- »Infected - I« (infected, infectious) and
- »Recovered - R« (Eliminated from the group of susceptible due to immunity
Illness, isolation or a fatal
Output)
including the → basic reproduction number
R0 can be calculated over time."

by Robert Koch Institut, Berlin (google translation)

https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/Service/Publikationen/Fachwoerterbuch_Infektionsschutz.pdf?__blob=publicationFile

also see:

*An SIR model is an epidemiological model that computes the theoretical number of people infected with a contagious illness in a closed population over time. The name of this class of models derives from the fact that they involve coupled equations relating the number of susceptible people S(t), number of people infected I(t), and number of people who have recovered R(t). One of the simplest SIR models is the Kermack-McKendrick model*.

The Season 1 episode "Vector" (2005) of the television crime drama NUMB3RS features SIR models.

SEE ALSO:
Kermack-McKendrick Model

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SIRModel.html